# Resources where I can find approachable applied literature to understand general chemistry topics?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, applied-chemistry

I am trying to find resources where I can learn about general chemistry topics outside the scope of a textbook, preferably in primary literature. Note, I have read through a general chemistry text and finished studying topics in the scope of a general chemistry course, so the informational foundation is there. My ideal "resource" is a place where I can find something akin to a 1-5 page experimental setup or design, or maybe a discussion, in which these concepts are applied and I'm forced to think about relationships in general chemistry, or what happens when things are changed. For example, I'd love to see some paper where I can see the ideal gas law applied as an approximation in the lungs or in deep sea divers, or some maybe some experiment where ion solubility is discussed in the scope of "hard water" in pipes. I know these applications exist, but I want to read about them on the level that makes me think about general chemistry concepts.

I can use VPN connections to login as a institution from my school and access some primary literature. However, sometimes I can't get full access becaue my institution is small and does not a subscription to a journal. Moreover, sometimes this primary literature is too complex in explanation, too longwinded, and goes beyond the scope of a general chemistry student. Now, I still want to think critically, but most of these papers include applications in engineering and use quantum physical assumptions beyond the scope of wave function solutions and electron configuration in general chemistry courses. My background includes a year of cell and molecular biology, an understanding of physics I and II, and math a little past integral calculus. I'd like the mathematics to be minimized, however, as I want concept.

Comment: You mean books on general chemistry? If that's the case, Atkins chemical principles is a really good book.

Comment: No, I don't mean general chemistry books. I've already read a general chemistry book. I want to read content that assumes you know general chemistry, but forces you to think critically about its applications as it pertains to the real world, experiments, etc. Something like a paper about gas laws in breathing, or ion solubility and treatment of hard water pipes.

Comment: While not perfect for what you looking for, the ACS Journal of Chemical Education often has articles directed towards applying basic chemical principles to real world situations. The articles are more geared towards educators, but I think it could be useful to you.